# calculating time difference between 201912 and JOIN_YM variables

Tags: r, rstudio, lubridate, as.date

- I have some data table which looks like this. [DATA] Customer ID :
  1255455 , 5258545 , 227484, 25485418 , 3745648 .....
         SEX :       1 ,       1 ,      2,        1 ,       2 .....
     JOIN_YM :  200608 , 201802  ,20170408,  201104 ,  201009 .....

  I just want to calculate the time difference between "2019/12/30" and
  the variables "JOIN_YM" In conclusion, I want to calculate the time
  spanned.

  Could you help me how to calculate this for using R programming.

Comment: Please add data in a reproducible format using `dput` and show expected output based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, calculating a timedifference can be obtained using difftime function (you can change the unit to your liking) . For parsing dates, I would suggest the `lubridate` package.

```
data <- data.frame(JOIN_YN="201802")
data %>% 
  mutate(
    timeSpanned = difftime(
      lubridate::ymd("2019-12-30"), 
      lubridate::ymd(paste0(JOIN_YN, "01")), 
      units = "days"
      )
    )
```